# How to reference a static class variable inside a namespace?

Tags: php, static, namespaces

Inside my php class Patient, I have a static method which init's some static class variables, which works fine. I do so like this:

```
private static $request;

public static function init() {
    self::$request = new Something();
}
```

But when I add a namespace to the top of the file, it dies on this line for some reason, and it's confusing me. Is there a special way to call static variables when inside a namespace?

Comment: do you have php errors enabled, and if so, what is the error?

Comment: Is the `Something` class in your namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code works when it's in the global namespace, but fails when it's in a custom namespace, you'll need to provide a fully-qualified class name whenever you use external classes.  So in this situation, simply change your code to:

```
public static function init() {
    self::$request = new \Something();
}
```

And if for some reason this doesn't solve your issue, then you can at least rule out static variables as being related to the problem by (temporarily) changing `self::$request =` to `$temp =` and observing that the problem still occurs.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you ☺️

Comment: Cheers!  Good luck with your project.